# Adding edges inside graph nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a graph and with multiple edges between the vertices.

[image: Original graph]

I would like to make the corresponding edges connect inside the node, for example, like this:

[image: Example of internal connections]

For starters, I tried adding a loop using `\path[-] (v1) edge [green] (v1);` but without any effect. I then looked into the PGF manual and discovered `/tikz/loop`, which has `in` and `out` parameters but those only seem to support angles around and outside the circle. `/tikz/loop above` does not seem to register the parameters at all.

This is my current code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = stealth, % arrow head style
        auto,
        node distance = 1cm, % distance between nodes
        semithick % line style
    ]

    \tikzstyle{every state}=[
        draw = black,
        thick,
        fill = white,
        minimum size = 4mm
    ]

    \node[state] (v1) [] {$1$};
    \node[state] (v2) [right of=v1] {$7$};
    \node[state] (v3) [right of=v2] {$1$};
    \node[state] (v4) [below of=v1] {$1$};

    \path[->] (v1) edge node {} (v2);
    \path[-] (v1) edge [bend left=60, orange] node {} (v2);
    \path[-] (v1) edge [bend left=30, orange] node {} (v2);
    \path[-] (v1) edge [bend left=45, orange] node {} (v2);
    \path[-] (v1) edge [bend left=15, purple] node {} (v2);
    \path[->] (v2) edge node {} (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend left=15, purple] node {} (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend left=30, purple] node {} (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend left=45, orange] node {} (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend left=60, orange] node {} (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend left=75, orange] node {} (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend right=15, teal] node {} (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend right=30, teal] node {} (v3);
    \path[->] (v4) edge node {} (v2);
    \path[-] (v4) edge [bend right=15, teal] node {} (v2);
    \path[-] (v4) edge [bend right=30, teal] node {} (v2);
    \path[-] (v4) edge [bend left=15, purple] node {} (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Reading the manual some more, I tried adding named nodes so I could refer to them in edges:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = stealth, % arrow head style
        % shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
        auto,
        node distance = 1cm, % distance between nodes
        semithick % line style
    ]

    \node[state] (v1) [] {$1$};
    \node[state] (v2) [right of=v1] {$7$};
    \node[state] (v3) [right of=v2] {$1$};
    \node[state] (v4) [below of=v1] {$1$};

    \path[->] (v1) edge (v2);
    \draw (v1) edge[bend left=15, purple] node {} (v2) node[pos=0, name=v1bl15s] {} node[pos=1, name=v1bl15t] {};
    \draw (v1) edge[bend left=30, orange] node {} (v2) node[pos=0, name=v1bl30s] {} node[pos=1, name=v1bl30t] {};
    \draw (v1) edge[bend left=45, orange] node {} (v2) node[pos=0, name=v1bl45s] {} node[pos=1, name=v1bl45t] {};
    \draw (v1) edge[bend left=60, orange] node {} (v2) node[pos=0, name=v1bl60s] {} node[pos=1, name=v1bl60t] {};
    \path[->] (v2) edge node {} (v3);
    \draw (v2) edge[bend left=15, purple] node {} (v3) node[pos=0, name=v2bl15s] {} node[pos=1, name=v2bl15t] {};
    \draw (v2) edge[bend left=30, purple] node {} (v3) node[pos=0, name=v2bl30s] {} node[pos=1, name=v2bl30t] {};
    \draw (v2) edge[bend left=45, orange] node {} (v3) node[pos=0, name=v2bl45s] {} node[pos=1, name=v2bl45t] {};
    \draw (v2) edge[bend left=60, orange] node {} (v3) node[pos=0, name=v2bl60s] {} node[pos=1, name=v2bl60t] {};
    \draw (v2) edge[bend left=75, orange] node {} (v3) node[pos=0, name=v2bl75s] {} node[pos=1, name=v2bl75t] {};
    \draw (v2) edge[bend right=15, teal] node {} (v3) node[pos=0, name=v2br15s] {} node[pos=1, name=v2br15t] {};
    \draw (v2) edge[bend right=30, teal] node {} (v3) node[pos=0, name=v2br30s] {} node[pos=1, name=v2br30t] {};
    \draw (v1bl15t) edge[purple] node {} (v2bl30s);
    \draw (v2bl15t) edge[purple] node {} (v2bl15s);
    \draw (v1bl30t) edge[orange] node {} (v2bl45s);
    \draw (v1bl45t) edge[orange] node {} (v2bl60s);
    \draw (v1bl60t) edge[orange] node {} (v2bl75s);
    \path[->] (v4) edge node {} (v2);
    \draw (v4) edge[bend right=15, teal] node {} (v2) node[pos=0, name=v4br15s] {} node[pos=1, name=v4br15t] {};
    \draw (v4) edge[bend right=30, teal] node {} (v2) node[pos=0, name=v4br30s] {} node[pos=1, name=v4br30t] {};
    \draw (v4) edge[bend left=15, purple] node {} (v2) node[pos=0, name=v4bl15s] {} node[pos=1, name=v4bl15t] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

That did not help and all the labels seem to point to the first node. When I switch the `edge` for `--`, the names start working but it is not compatible with bending since it is a straight line.

Comment: The issue at the end can be resolved as follows: instead of `\draw (v1) edge[bend left=15, purple] node {} (v2) node[pos=0, name=v1bl15s] {} node[pos=1, name=v1bl15t] {};` you need `\draw (v1) edge[bend left=15, purple] node {} node[pos=0, name=v1bl15s] {} node[pos=1, name=v1bl15t] {} (v2) ;`. Note the position of `(v2)`. For a `--` path both ways work, as you say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle it is not very difficult to draw these but you have a huge number of nodes and connections. So here is something that may help you constructing a solution but it is not a complete solution. You can record the coordinates at which the edges hit the node boundaries. The number of such coordinates is enormous. So here is some auto labeling mechanism that gives the node nodes names

```
p-<pos>-<start>-<target>-<bend angle>
```

where the position `pos` is either `0` or `1`, `start` denotes the start node, `target` the node where the edge ends and the `bend angle` is the bend angle used in the path. Ironically even this doesn't make the names unique because Ti*k*Z does not store the sign of the angle in the macro I am using. Anyway, these coordinates can be used to extend the edges through the nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = stealth, % arrow head style
        auto,
        node distance = 1cm, % distance between nodes
        semithick % line style
    ]
\makeatletter
\tikzset{autoname0/.code={%
    \tikzset{pos=0,alias=p-0-\tikztostart-\tikztotarget-\tikz@to@bend}},
        autoname1/.code={%
    \tikzset{pos=1,alias=p-1-\tikztostart-\tikztotarget-\tikz@to@bend}%
    }}
\makeatother

    \tikzset{every state/.style={
        draw = black,
        thick,
        fill = white,
        minimum size = 4mm}}

    \node[state] (v1) [] {$1$};
    \node[state] (v2) [right of=v1] {$7$};
    \node[state] (v3) [right of=v2] {$1$};
    \node[state] (v4) [below of=v1] {$1$};

    \path[->] (v1) edge node {} (v2);
    \path[-] (v1) edge [bend left=60, orange] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v2);
    \path[-] (v1) edge [bend left=30, orange] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v2);
    \path[-] (v1) edge [bend left=45, orange] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v2);
    \path[-] (v1) edge [bend left=15, purple] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v2);
    \path[->] (v2) edge coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend left=15, purple] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend left=30, purple] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend left=45, orange] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend left=60, orange] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend left=75, orange] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend right=15, teal] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v3);
    \path[-] (v2) edge [bend right=30, teal] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v3);
    \path[->] (v4) edge coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v2);
    \path[-] (v4) edge [bend right=15, teal] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v2);
    \path[-] (v4) edge [bend right=30, teal] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v2);
    \path[-] (v4) edge [bend left=20, purple] coordinate[autoname0] (aux) coordinate[autoname1](aux) (v2);
    \foreach \X/\Y in {60/75,45/60,30/45}
    {\draw[orange] (p-1-v1-v2-\X) to[bend right={\X/2+\Y/2}] (p-0-v2-v3-\Y);}
    \foreach \X/\Y in {15/15,30/30}
    {\draw[teal] (p-1-v4-v2-\X) to[bend left={\X/2+\Y/2+30}] (p-0-v2-v3-\Y);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As I said, this is not a complete solution but perhaps some of it can be used somewhere. The orange connections look reasonable, for the teal ones one has to add the angle v3-v2-v4.

Comment: Oooh, that's a good one ! The trick to automate the alias is very nice !

Comment: @BambOo Thanks! But it isn't really as successful in the end as I thought it might be. I like your solution, it is very simple.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to keep things as simple as can be. I am very lazy !

Comment: @BambOo Are you a cat? ;-)

Comment: No, I am not, but I am a bamboo, what pandas use for food, so I let you imagine !

Comment: @BambOo Then I know [where I can find you](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzlings/tikzlings-pandas.sty). ;-)

Comment: So it seeems :)

Comment: I like this solution, especially the automation. While you answered, I was attempting to create labels manually (see the edit) but did not succeed. I even tried substituting `node[pos=0, name=v1bl15s] {}` for `coordinate[pos=0, alias=v1bl15s] (aux)` from your solution but that did not work either. Could you please elaborate on what does the macro expand to or where I am making mistake when trying to replicate it manually?

Comment: @JanTojnar A node is an extended object so you will have gaps, a coordinate is just a point. Other than that I am wondering where you put these nodes/coordinates, before the or after the target? If you put it after it won't work.

Comment: @JanTojnar I just realized you added the code. So indeed instead of `\draw (v1) edge[bend left=15, purple] node {} (v2) node[pos=0, name=v1bl15s] {} node[pos=1, name=v1bl15t] {};` you need `\draw (v1) edge[bend left=15, purple] node {} node[pos=0, name=v1bl15s] {} node[pos=1, name=v1bl15t] {} (v2) ;`. Note the position of `(v2)`. For a `--` path both ways work, as you say.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand both the distinction between `node` and `coordinate` and the reason why it did not work. I am still somewhat unclear on whether `(foo)` always creates a new label, refers to the existing object with a label, or it is context-sensitive – if I understand it correctly, `(aux)` labels the `coordinate` objects all with the same label. Will the label apply only to last object labelled as such? It seems to be the case as I can label the objects directly: `coordinate[pos=0] (p-0-v5-t-61)`.

Comment: Sections *11.5 Special Syntax for Specifying Nodes*, *14 Syntax for Path Specifications* (especially *14.17 The Node and Edge Operations*) and *17 Nodes and Edges* (especially *17.2.1 Syntax of the Node Command*, *17.11 Connecting Nodes: Using Nodes as Coordinates* and *17.12 Connecting Nodes: Using the Edge Operation*) in the PGF manual explain the syntax and cleared up my questions.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/6e8397b58f2b9dbf110ca0da12c9791c9cbdd191/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex#L30-L53), I am guessing that maybe the value of `180-\tikz@to@in` could be used to distinguish between `bend left` (negative) and `bend right` (positive). Not sure how to include the calculations, though, so I went with `15ɑ` values for left bends and `15ɑ+1` for right bends.

Comment: @JanTojnar Yes, these are the appropriate sections, I think. It is a repeated source of confusion that for `--` paths you can put the "timed" coordinates after target but not for bent ones. And yes, I agree on your statement on the source code. The story behind this is that the purpose here was really only to have some style that does something along those lines, and that was the first thing that came to my mind, I did not think deeply about what the best discriminator could be, and there could well be better ones.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure one can easily do what you demand without specifiying the *polar anchors* e.g `<node>.<angle>` for each `path` which could be quite cumbersome.

Instead, I propose to point towards the center of the `node`s to have the `path`s go through your `node`s but to draw these on the `background` layer and to fill the `node`s with a partial `opacity` in order to not disturb the `node` content too much.

I also modified some of your settings since part of them are deprecated:

- `\tikzstyle{<style name>}[<style content>]` has been superseeded by `\tikzset{<stlye name>/.style={<style content>}`
- The relative positioning keys of the `positioning` library should now be used as `<direction> = of <node>` and node `<direction> of =  <node>`

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,backgrounds,positioning}
\tikzset{state/.style={
    draw = black,
    thick,
    fill = white,
    fill opacity=0.6,
    text opacity=1,
    circle,
    minimum size = 4mm
}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = stealth, % arrow head style
    % shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
    auto,
    node distance = 1cm, % distance between nodes
    semithick % line style
]


\node[state] (v1) [] {$1$};
\node[state] (v2) [right = of v1] {$7$};
\node[state] (v3) [right = of v2] {$1$};
\node[state] (v4) [below = of v1] {$1$};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path[->] (v1) edge node {} (v2);
\path[-] (v1.center) edge [bend left=60, orange] node {} (v2.center);
\path[-] (v1.center) edge [bend left=30, orange] node {} (v2.center);
\path[-] (v1.center) edge [bend left=45, orange] node {} (v2.center);
\path[-] (v1.center) edge [bend left=15, purple] node {} (v2.center);
\path[->] (v2) edge node {} (v3);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend left=15, purple] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend left=30, purple] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend left=45, orange] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend left=60, orange] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend left=75, orange] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend right=15, teal] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend right=30, teal] node {} (v3.center);
\path[->] (v4) edge node {} (v2);
\path[-] (v4.center) edge [bend right=15, teal] node {} (v2.center);
\path[-] (v4.center) edge [bend right=30, teal] node {} (v2.center);
\path[-] (v4.center) edge [bend left=15, purple] node {} (v2.center);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** If for some reason, you do not like the partial opacity, you could use the `contour` package which renders a contour around letters by replication of the original text.

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,backgrounds,positioning}
\tikzset{state/.style={
    draw = black,
    thick,
    fill = white,
    fill opacity=0,
    text opacity=1,
    circle,
    minimum size = 4mm
}
}
% Distance between original letters and replicates
\contourlength{0.05em}
% Amount of replicates
\contournumber{30}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = stealth, % arrow head style
    % shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
    auto,
    node distance = 1cm, % distance between nodes
    semithick % line style
]


\node[state] (v1) [] {\contour{white}{$1$}};
\node[state] (v2) [right = of v1] {\contour{white}{$7$}};
\node[state] (v3) [right = of v2] {\contour{white}{$1$}};
\node[state] (v4) [below = of v1] {\contour{white}{$1$}};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path[->] (v1) edge node {} (v2);
\path[-] (v1.center) edge [bend left=60, orange] node {} (v2.center);
\path[-] (v1.center) edge [bend left=30, orange] node {} (v2.center);
\path[-] (v1.center) edge [bend left=45, orange] node {} (v2.center);
\path[-] (v1.center) edge [bend left=15, purple] node {} (v2.center);
\path[->] (v2) edge node {} (v3);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend left=15, purple] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend left=30, purple] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend left=45, orange] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend left=60, orange] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend left=75, orange] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend right=15, teal] node {} (v3.center);
\path[-] (v2.center) edge [bend right=30, teal] node {} (v3.center);
\path[->] (v4) edge node {} (v2);
\path[-] (v4.center) edge [bend right=15, teal] node {} (v2.center);
\path[-] (v4.center) edge [bend right=30, teal] node {} (v2.center);
\path[-] (v4.center) edge [bend left=15, purple] node {} (v2.center);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool solution, especially the contours and background scope. Thanks for pointing out the deprecations.